# Accessing sequence created in oracle database from php script

Tags: php, oracle, sequence

I have created  sequence in database like,

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq INCREMENT BY 1;
```

How can i assign the current value of seq in $t;

```
<?php

$t=?;

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the next value from the sequence you would run the sql statement below and fetch back the results of the myseq column.

```
select seq.nextval myseq
  from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

Run this query and fetch the result of it:

```
SELECT seq.CURRVAL FROM dual
```

Comment: Won't work unless the session has previously called seq.NEXTVAL.